# Adding a service to Android manifest with difficult package structure (LibGDX) / Referencing packages in Android Manifest

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-service, android-manifest

We are programming with LibGDX and our package Structure looks as follows:

[image: package structure of our Android Project]

I've an own Android Service in the server package that I want to add to my Android Manifest - but the server package is not known to the editor. Android Studio searches in the core package but not in the java package.

[image: Our Android Manifest file]

As you can see circled in blue our package in the manifest is com.mxgdx.game
In the image's bottom you can see that I can access the class Hud in core -> java -> com.mygdx.game.Scenes (this class isn't a Service) but I can't access the server package where my Service is in. I've also tried accessing it by

- "java.server." (server was already unknown)
- "android.java." (java was already unknown)
- "android.server" (server was already unknown)

*This is for a university project, we are pretty new the android and an explanation would be welcome. I guess it's a really easy problem, but I tried googling for pretty long and just can't think of any new search terms. My basic problem is that my onBind() doesn't run and I came here because of CommonsWare's answer to this question: [onBind() is never called in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909217/onbind-is-never-called-in-a-service) - so if there is another possibility without adding my service to the manifest, would be great as well, but the official documentation seems to make clear that is not possible https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I tried **looking on the file structure of my project on hard disk** level and I don't know why but I never thought of just trying to begin with **"server.MyService"** - that finally worked. Maybe this helps somebody one time - *otherwise sorry for spamming haha*